# How to achieve Table API's "over aggregation" by custom trigger/process-function using the DataStream API?

Tags: apache-flink

For per record/row it is needed to achieve over aggregations(window functions).
This does not look like the SlidingEventTimeWindows provided by the DataStream API. It looks to me more like a customized EventTimeSessionWindows with a customized trigger as for each record/row it is needed to trigger the calculation

But how does the single-record window know all the values from the past N seconds?

Below is the SQL I have - need to convert it into DataStream API for better control.

```
Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
    "SELECT " +
    " userId," +
    " eventEpoch," +
    " AVG(valueA) OVER w1 AS AVG_VALUE_B" +
    " FROM InputTable " +
    " WINDOW w1 AS (" +
    " PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY rowtime" +
    " RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '" + 20 + "' SECOND PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)"
);
```